# How to set the Navigation bar in the top of the html page?

Tags: html, css, django

I developed an **index.html** page in django project. The below is the template code I developed. Right now, the navigation bar is coming at the bottom

**index.html**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #dddddd
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Contact Book Template</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/style.css' %}" />
  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <img class="contact_book" src="{% static 'img/contact_book.jpg' %}" alt="first" />
  <div id="booking" class="section">
    <div>
      <ul id="horizantal-style">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">Sign up</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am expecting it to set the navigation bar at the top, could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your HTML markup a little bit. Put the image tag after the menu.
If you want to place an image before the menu it's also possible to wrap everything in a flex container and change the order of items, but it's overhead for this task.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #dddddd
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Contact Book Template</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/style.css' %}" />

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul id="horizontal-style">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <img class="contact_book" src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" alt="first" />

  <div id="booking" class="section">
    <!-- Rest of the page content here -->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made two examples using some altered markup to not use `ul` and `li` items which gives a slight bit of flexibility in the layout so we can then style with independent html blocks in the header to push them each direction using `grid` css

First example shows the provided small set with some ugly borders and padding to show what is where.

The second build on this with a commonly seen addition to a navigation as a header.

Why: Review the second example to see the "header" with content and a footer.

```css
* {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
  width: 100vw;
}

.nav-container {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: solid #00FF00 1px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.nav-group {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 1px #FF00FF;
}

.nav-links {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(5rem, 1fr));
}

.nav-actions {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(5rem, 1fr));
  justify-self: end;
}

.nav-item {
  text-align center;
  border: solid #FFFF00 1px;
}

.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 1.25em;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  background-color: #00000044;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.active {
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/style.css' %}" />
  <link rel="preload" as="image" href="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section">
    <div>
      <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav-group nav-links">
          <div class="nav-item linker"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
          <div class="nav-item linker"><a href="#">News</a></div>
          <div class="nav-item linker"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-group nav-actions">
          <div class="nav-item login"><a href="#">Login</a></div>
          <div class="nav-item signup"><a class="active" href="#about">Sign up</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Why not use `li`: here I add some additional markup:

```css
* {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #00ffff22;
}

.page-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  background-color: #ddaa0022;
}

.section {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.nav-container {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00000044;
}

.footer-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 3rem;
}

.nav-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3rem;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 0;

}

.nav-item {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-links {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.nav-actions {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  justify-self: end;
}

.nav-item {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-item a {
  padding: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.75em;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  background-color: #00000044;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.active {
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/style.css' %}" />
  <link rel="preload" as="image" href="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page-container">
    <div class="section nav-container">
      <div class="nav-group nav-links">
        <div class="nav-item linker"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item linker"><a href="#">News</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item linker"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-group nav-actions">
        <div class="nav-item login"><a href="#">Login</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item signup"><a class="active" href="#about">Sign up</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section content-container">HI I am here
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500"alt="I am image">
    </div>
    <div class="section footer-container">I am after
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```